# GL10 GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT on android

Tags: android, jogl

is it possible to use GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT in jogl ES (GL10) ?? and if is affect version of jogl ES , i use version 2 ( hopped be compatible with mach devices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't make a confusion between [JOGL](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/) and [Android OpenGL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/package-summary.html). JOGL-ES does no longer exist as a separate library, it was merged into JOGL 2.x several years ago.

GL_MIRROR_REPEAT is [here](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/javax/media/opengl/GL.html#GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT). You can use it with OpenGL-ES 2.0, OpenGL 1.4 and later (with a backward compatible profile) and under OpenGL-ES 1 if and only if the extension GL_OES_texture_mirrored_repeat is supported.

Comment: that mean i can use GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT if i use GL20 instead of GL10 ?

Comment: GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT is in android.opengl.GLES20: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLES20.html#GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT

Comment: but for example in my case if have a render for function onSurfaceCreated, changed and onDrawFrame need change GL10 with GLES20 ? that not affect my Render ? or need only modify when want use gl_mirrored_repeat take from GLES20.GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT ?

Comment: I don't know as you use Android GL whereas I use JOGL 2. I'm lazy, I prefer using the same source code in desktop and mobile environments. As far as I know, some methods and extensions are only present in OpenGL-ES 2 and vice versa, mixing ES 1 and ES 2 can become challenging :s

Comment: then you mean to use JOGL2 and in android ? if more better then use Android GL ?

Comment: Yes, watch this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHxtVT4tWjM JOGL on several platforms :) It's a bit painful at the beginning but when it works, it can be a time saver. The problem is that tons of library for Android are written for Android GL.